# The long SMS is converted to MMS and shows sending. How do I make sure it is sent?

Tags: mms

I typed a long message and it was converted to a multimedia message. When I press the send button it shows "sending" but never shows "sent". How do I know it has been sent or not?

Answer (score 2):

It hasn't. The status would change if the message went through. Now you'll have to check you MMS settings from `Messaging ->`<kbd>menu</kbd>`-> Settings -> Multimedia message settings` and your MMS APN from `Settings -> Wireless -> Mobile networks -> Access point names` (or `Settings -> More.. -> Mobile networks -> Access point names` in newer versions).

After you have corrected these and verified that your carrier/operator has enabled MMS on your account, the message should be sent. Or you have to long-press it and select `Retry`.